# ALINK : error AL1078: Error signing assembly -- Unknown error (8013141c)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm just using Visual Studio 2017/2019 and facing these errors, I have tried several ways:

1/ Give Full Control to everyone and Administrator

2/ Update the Nuget Package

It seems the error is coming from the system( Window OS) not the source code or my solution its self.

[image: My administrator have Full Control]

Comment: Does this help? http://www.timferro.com/wordpress/archives/1062

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I guess it's not.